# Allowing dash in string but not several consecutive dashes

Tags: php, regex

This is a regex where string must start and end with an alphanumeric character and can contain alphanumeric characters and dashes.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}$/
```

How can I make sure that the consecutive dashes are not allowed? for example:

```
should allow: some-string

should NOT allow: some--string
```

Thanks

Edit: I want to allow several dashes, just not consecutively. for example "some-thing-here" is OK, and "some--thing" is NOT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for complicated patterns with optional dashes just use this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?301d0)

Start with at least one alphanumeric. Then there can be a dash followed by at least one alphanumerics 0 ore more times.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution. Thanks. Also thanks for regexer link, awesome. Just curious: doesn't (- need to be (\-   ?

Comment: @Leo, sorry overlooked your question in the comment. No you don't need to escape the `-`, only inside a character class, where it has a special meaning (range e.g. `a-z`)

Comment: This does not work for strings ending in a dash: "foo-"

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+-?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

`?` for "occuring zero or one time"

To allow multiple pieces separated with one dash, change it to:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/
```

The `(...)*` says that the last group (starting with a `-`) may be repeated zero or more times.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\-?([a-zA-Z0-9]+\-?)*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}$/
```

The key part being `\-?([a-zA-Z0-9]+\-?)*` which makes it read "a letter/number, optional dash, any amount of (some letters/numbers, optionally followed by a dash), ending in a letter or number."

This allows `some-string`, `my-double-dash-string` but not `my-double--dash-string`.

Comment: Stema, are you just going round -1'ing all my answers for the hell of it? It's based off his own regex, so it's easier for him to see where his current regex goes wrong. Sure it's a bit longwinded, but it's not overly crazy-long

Comment: @Joe sorry didn't recognize it was you the second time. Its not you, personally and I think I explained each time, what I don't like at the answers. And an answer based on what the OP originally posted is not always the best solution. (The good thing for you, you got for both answers more rep than you lost ;))

Comment: @stema it is generally not polite to downvote on "competing" answers that are not blatantly wrong. I also got a strange uncommented downvote on my answer (identical to yours), while my last edit was done 1 minute prior to your answer posted.

Comment: @mvds if I would have downvoted you, I would have explained whats in my opinion wrong. And its my decision to downvote and answer when I think its not a good answer and I try all the time to explain why and if the answer is improved I will remove the downvote.

Comment: In most cases, there's not a whole lot of point improving the answer, this question is a case in point: Yours in shorter, cleaner and will run faster, and has been accepted. Better to leave this here as an alternative, for comparison. Nowt will be gained by just making it identical to yours :P Obviously there is a point when there's no accepted answer, or when an answer is plain wrong

Answer (score 0):

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+-?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`
Should work I believe. You don't need to differentiate the initial and ending group of the alphanumberical characters. Simply expect each dash to be surronded by such character.

Comment: Although correct, `[X]` is saying "any character in the set X", which is more easily put as just `X`. For `{0,1}` we have the convenient shorthand `?`.

Comment: Thank you. I was not sure if `?` is present in php.